# Python: how to obtain a list of lists when you are using two loops and a conditional?

Tags: python, list, loops, conditional-statements

I have a list of lists like this:

```
column = ["column1", "column2","column3","column4","column5", "column6","column7","column8"],["column1", "column2","column3","column4","column5", "column6","column7","column8"]
list = ["app","bq","bq","11","app","bq","bq","10"],["all","bq","appleuu","110","app","bq","bq","10"]
```

I want to build a loop that will give me the elements of column 4 and 8 only if column 1 and 5 are equal to "app".

So this is the code that I wrote:

```
for element in list:
  for part in range(0,len(element)-1):
    if element[part] == "app":
      apps_numbers.append(element[part+3])
print(apps_numbers)
```

The problem is that this just gives me a list of all the numbers `['11', '10', '10']` instead of a list of list (maintaining the structure of my original list of list, so: `[[11,10],[10]]`)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like you really don't care about the column header list.  The code can completely ignore that, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you are not concerned about the column headers.  You need to check the first and fourth elements of each row, and create a list for each row.

```
element_list = [["app","bq","bq","11","app","bq","bq","10"],
     ["all", "bq", "appleuu", "110", "app", "bq", "bq", "10"]]

newlist = []
for row in element_list:
    rowlist = []
    if row[0] == "app":
        rowlist.append(row[3])
    if row[4] == "app":
        rowlist.append(row[7])
    newlist.append(rowlist)

print(newlist)
```

Output:

```
[['11', '10'], ['10']]
```

As was stated, you cannot name a list with the word "list" as that is a keyword in python.

Answer (score 0):

Why not a list comprehension, dont use list as variable name

```
column = [["column1", "column2","column3","column4","column5", "column6","column7","column8"],["column1", "column2","column3","column4","column5", "column6","column7","column8"]]
mylist = ["app","bq","bq","11","app","bq","bq","10"],["all","bq","appleuu","110","app","bq","bq","10"]

newlist = [[x[3],x[7]] for x,y in zip(column,mylist) if (y[0] == "app") and (y[4] == "app")]

print(newlist)
```